# Getting an Objective-C class name without having a MonoTouch managed class

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, translate

I can't for the life of me figure out how to translate this into MonoTouch. Any takers?

```
for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
{
    if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
    {
    }
}
```

Mostly it's the View Class Description that has me stumped...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, [@Monoman's `is` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11655492/63225) is the right way to find instances of a particular class, even when you're looking for a CocoaTouch class from within a MonoTouch program.

Sometimes, however, you'll discover that there's an internal CocoaTouch class that's not exposed in MonoTouch (or even in the iOS Platform headers). In such a case, you'll have to resort to [tricks like @poupou is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11657997/63225).

Unfortunately, his answers won't work here *either*. `view.GetType()` is returning the most-derived MonoTouch type that each `Subview` implements, and then `ToString()`, `Class.Name`, or even `@selector("description")` each operate on the wrong type and give an overly generic answer ("`UIView`" in this case).

In order to make this work, you'll have to go one layer *deeper* under the covers than @poupou proposed.

```
// ** using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime; **

private string GetClassName (IntPtr obj) {
    Selector description = new Selector ("description");
    Selector cls = new Selector ("class");
    IntPtr viewcls = Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (obj, cls.Handle);
    var name = NSString.FromHandle (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (viewcls, description.Handle));
    return name;
}
```

Here's an alternative that's not a whole lot more fiddly (maybe even less?), but will work on any Objective-C class, not just those that respond to `NSObject`'s `description` message:

```
// ** using System.Runtime.InteropServices; **

[DllImport ("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib")]
private static extern IntPtr object_getClassName (IntPtr obj);

private string GetClassName (IntPtr obj) {
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(object_getClassName(obj));
}
```

It's actually surprising and a little bit sad that MonoTouch doesn't provide an import for `object_getClassName()` already.

You would use either one of those like so:

```
foreach (UIView view in cell.Subviews) {
    if (GetClassName(view.Handle) == "UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
    }
}
```

**Big fat disclaimer**: Pretty much any time you're resorting to tricks like these, you're relying on CocoaTouch implementation details that Apple reserves the right to change. Rule of thumb: if you can do what you want with @Monoman's solution, you're *probably* safe. Otherwise, you're taking matters in to your own hands.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not using Monotouch currently, but shouldn't you just check the managed type of the subview?

```
   foreach (UIView view in cell.subviews)
   {
     if (view is UITableViewCellReorderControl) {}
   }
```

Comment: Yep, the original *direct* is mostly doing: `view.GetType ().ToString ()` where `[view class]` returns the type and `description` return the name (`description` is also used, by default, for `NSObject.ToString()`. However the *adapted* translation from @Monoman is better to represent what this means.

Comment: And if System.Linq is available you could abbreviate it further: `foreach(var view in cell.subViews.OfType<UITableViewCellReorderControl>())`

Comment: foreach (UIView subView in cell.Subviews)
    {
     if(subView is UITableViewCellReorderControl)
     {
     
     }
    }
throws error: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UITableViewCellReorderControl' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (CS0246)

Comment: This won't work in this case because `UITableViewCellReorderControl` is a deep `UIKit` internal.

Answer (score 5):

The handling of Objective-C `Class` is mostly hidden in the API provided by MonoTouch. It's mostly the `System.Type` and `description` is mostly the `ToString` - but that won't show some internals.

Here's a few things (simple to more complex) you can try:

Calling `ToString` on the `view` instance *might* include the original class name (as part of the description) - but it's not the same as calling `description` of the `class` itself.

```
 foreach (UIView view in cell.Subviews) {
    if (view.ToString ().Contains ("UITableViewCellReorderControl")) {
    }
 }
```

Next try to see if `Name` on `Class` is identical to `description`.

```
foreach (UIView view in cell.Subviews) {
   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class c = new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class (view.GetType ());
   if (c.Name == "UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
   }
}
```

Finally really call the `description` selector on the `Class` instance. Something like (untried):

```
MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector description = new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector ("description");
foreach (UIView view in cell.Subviews) {
   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class c = new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class (view.GetType ());
   var name = NSString.FromHandle (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (c.Handle, description.Handle));
   if (name == "UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
   }
}
```

Comment: I fixed up and tested your third one. None of these capture the types in the OP's case. I've added an answer with a couple of implementations that I've tested to work.

Comment: Works great! But now I have to figure out where to implement so that the cells in the table get a new location of the ReorderControl. If I put it in WillDisplay, everything looks good until I actually move a cell. Then all cells that move revert back to original control placement. Any thoughts on which Method will update the setting after a move?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
foreach(var subview in this.ContentView.Superview.Subviews)
{
    if(subview.Class.Name.EndsWith("UITableViewCellReorderControl"))
    {
    }
}
```