# Finding the location of a UITabBarItem in Monotouch Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin

Im trying to implement my own popup menu from a UITabBar. 
My app allows users to specify which menus are displayed on the tab bar and I'm not keen on the default "More" button that iOS uses when there are a lot of tab bar items so I would like to create some of the tab bar items to be "Sub menus" that pup up a menu of further buttons. I would like it to pop up from the tabbaritem itself and the order of the tabs may not be the same for every user. 
So far I can find the tabbaritem the user has selected but next i need to know its location so I can animate a popup menu from that location.

Does anyone know how I could go about finding the frame or position of the selected tabbaritem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate trough the subviews of your `UITabBar` and get only those subviews which are a type of `UITabBarButton` class. Then you get the frame of the subviews you are interested in.

```
List<RectangleF> tabBarButtonFrames = new List<RectangleF>();

foreach (var view in this.tabBarController.TabBar.Subviews) {
    if (view.ToString().Contains("UITabBarButton")) {
        tabBarButtonFrames.Add(view.Frame);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(view.ToString() + "\t" + view.Frame.ToString());
}
```

Note: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11657997/1441667) contains more ways of getting the Objective-C class names  from [poupou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220643/poupou)